# Upload pdf threw ui components

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a pdf in custom form, but i'm failing. My controller doesn't seems to receive the data.

```
    <field name="pdf" sortOrder="100" formElement="fileUploader">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">booklet</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Booklet Pdf</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <required>false</required>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <fileUploader>
                <settings>
                    <previewTmpl>Sesa_Booklet/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    <required>true</required>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="booklet/pdf/upload"/>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <allowedExtensions>pdf</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                </settings>
            </fileUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

On the save controller; this is null

```
        $pdfParam = $this->_request->getParam('pdf');
```

I followed the image way to try it

```
<virtualType name="Sesa\Booklet\FileUpload" type="Sesa\Booklet\Model\FileUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">booklet_file/upload</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">booklet_file/upload</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">pdf</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Sesa\Booklet\Controller\Adminhtml\Pdf\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="fileUploader" xsi:type="object">Sesa\Booklet\FileUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And this is my file upload

```
/**
 * Upload file controller action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $result = $this->fileUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('pdf');

        $result['cookie'] = [
            'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
            'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
    }
    return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
}
```

EDIT : I can see an error in console log when i upload the file which is a non sense as the variable is declared in my di xml as you can see.

> jquery.js:10260          POST http://sesam2.dev.fr/admin_sesa/booklet/pdf/upload/key/42a49dd945be5be5ae1206722a39a2a3ad1fd44d2ee1c774ec15934a4e889384/?isAjax=true 500 (Internal Server Error)
> Show 2 more frames
> file-uploader.js:396 1 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $baseTmpPath of Sesa\Booklet\Model\FileUploader.